# Adding webservice PUT/GET inside Result

Tags: java, playframework, ws

Would you like to help me to add some code about : PUT/GET methods about an exemple of Web services  as shown in ( SOAP UI ) please :

I admit that the documentation on the official play-framework website is a bit tricky for my beginner level especially when it comes to: JsonNode, Promise, ...

[image]

```
public CompletionStage<Result> index() {
  return supplyAsync(() -> {
      
    WSRequest request = ws.url("https://test.portnet.ma/portnet/PortnetMessageReceiverService?wsdl"); 
    
    Logger.info("TEST Logger Info : "+request.get());
    
    //1-3   Request :    Some code to submit >>     put   or   post    methode
    
    //2-3   Response :   Some code to get >> parameters values as shown in SOAP UI      

    //3-3   Finally display Response infos in my view if possible as "String"

    return ok(views.html.sitemap.index.render( ));
    }, httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect to another page?

Comment: Thank you Niko for your help, i would like to add some code to ( make connection  REQUEST + RESPONSE ) between my application and a webservice such as :